# Java: How to get current date in ISO 8601 SECOND format

Tags: java, date, timezone, format, iso

I need to get the current date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with **SS milliseconds** and **HH:MM timezone**

Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
second: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.**45+01:00**)

see: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

i tried different approaches, but i cannot get the correct milliseconds & timezone digits:

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZZ");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
df.format(new Date());
```

**JAVA result:** 2012-11-24T21:19:27.**758+0000**

**Apache result:** 2012-11-24T21:19:27.**758+00:00** (Apache Commons FastDateFormat)

Comment: Milli-seconds is `SSS` not `SS`

Comment: Yes... that question has very complete answers.

Comment: No, not a duplicate. This question is about *generating* strings while the other is about *parsing* strings.

Comment: @Cœur I did not realize that auto-generated text remained after reopening. Now fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is a class in JDK that handles parsing and formatting ISO8601:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(new GregorianCalendar())
//2012-11-24T22:42:03.142+01:00
```

Comment: My confusion was that all the examples show 2 digit milliseconds, but the ISO docs really say: Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a ***decimal fraction*** of a second

Comment: @marcolopes  The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard allows any number of digits after the decimal place for as fine a fraction of a second as you desire, provided the recipient of your data can handle that granularity. For milliseconds, you need three decimal places, for microseconds six digits, and for nanoseconds nine digits. Note that old date-time classes use millis, databases like Postgres use micros, and the java.time classes use nanos.

Comment: This Answer provided a good workaround back in the old days. Now fortunately we have the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later, with back-ports for Java 6 & 7 and for Android.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

### Current moment, UTC

Use `java.time.Instant` to capture the current moment in a resolution as fine as nanoseconds.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture the current moment in UTC, with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds. Typically captured in microseconds in Java 9 and later, milliseconds in Java 8.
.toString()    // Generate a `String` representing the value of this `Instant` in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z

The `Z` on the end:

- means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time),
- is equivalent to `+00:00` [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset),
- is pronounced “Zulu”, and
- is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard as well as other arenas such as military.

### Current moment, specific offset

If for some unusual reason you must adjust into a specific [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), passing a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
OffsetDateTime.now(          // Capture the current moment.
    ZoneOffset.ofHours( 1 )  // View the current moment adjusted to the wall-clock time of this specific offset-from-UTC. BTW, better to use time zones, generally, than a mere offset-from-UTC.
)
.toString()                  // Generate a `String` in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-07-08T21:13:10.723676+01:00

### Current moment, truncated to millis

For milliseconds resolution, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). Specify resolution by [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
OffsetDateTime.now( 
    ZoneOffset.ofHours( 1 ) 
)
.truncatedTo(               // Lop off finer part of the date-time. We want to drop any microseconds or nanoseconds, so truncate to milliseconds. Using the immutable objects pattern, so a separate new `OffsetDateTime` object is generated based on the original object’s values.
    ChronoUnit.MILLIS       // Specify your desired granularity via `ChronoUnit` enum.
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-07-08T21:13:10.723+01:00

## java.time

The [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) be default when parsing or generating textual representations of date-time values.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

The current moment is captured with a resolution of milliseconds in Java 8, and in Java 9 and later, typically a resolution of microseconds depending on capabilities of host hardware clock and OS. If you specifically want milliseconds resolution, truncate any microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ) ;
```

But you want a specific [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So specify a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset( "+01:00" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , offset );
```

Again, truncate if you specifically want milliseconds resolution rather than microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
odt = odt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ) ;  // Replace original `OffsetDateTime` object with new `OffsetDateTime` object based on the original but with any micros/nanos lopped off.
```

To generate your ISO 8601 string, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = odt.toString();
```

Dump to console. Note in the output how the hour rolled forward as an adjustment to the `+01:00` offset, and that even rolled over midnight so the date changed from the 12th to the 13th.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | offset: " + offset + " | odt: " + odt );
```

> instant: 2016-04-12T23:12:24.015Z | offset: +01:00 | odt: 2016-04-13T00:12:24.015+01:00

## Zoned

By the way, it is better to use a time zone (if known) than just a mere offset. A time zone a history of the past, present, and future changes in offset used by the people of a particular region.

In java.time that means applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Or skip `Instant`, as a shortcut.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

Generate a `String` representing textually the value of that `ZonedDateTime` object. The format used by default is standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

> zdt.toString(): 2018-07-08T22:06:58.780923+02:00[Europe/Paris]

For other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).